# How can the user save a form and access it later?

Tags: html, forms, input, save

I have made a form and I want the user to have this option to type into the form and have the ability to close the page and open it again and see the text they have typed into the form. Do I have to use a database?

Here's my form:

```
<form action="" name="form1">
    <label>Enter the title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="title">
    <label>Enter the description: </label>
    <textarea name="description" class="description">

    <!--Here's the save button-->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="savebtn">
</form>
```

I'm also not sure if I have to use a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offline storage capabilities of HTML5.

See [Client-Side Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different solutions.

The easiest way I would think of is to use a cookie, you can find how to create and manage cookie with easy javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Then with some simple javascript code, when you load the page you just check if there is a cookie, if there is you retrieve the data and populate the form.